# Adding an Image to ListView in WPF like this ...?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listview, binding

I'm gonna create a ListView in WPF like the below image 
[image: ListView in WPF]
<sub>(source: [picfront.org](http://www7.picfront.org/picture/ZcYGCAbgtG/thb/FF3-bookmark-manager.jpg))</sub>
 
http://www.picfront.org/d/7xuv
I mean I wanna add an image beside of `Gravatar` label within `Name` column. 
Would it be OK if you guided me ?

Edit: 
The image is output of a method. The method makes the image from a base-64 string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As long as you're already familiar with how to data bind a ListView then it's pretty simple really. In your cell template you would just need a StackPanel with an Image and a TextBlock side by side.

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding IconUri}"/>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
      <GridViewColumn ... />
      <GridViewColumn ... />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: @Josh: Thanks Josh. But as I said I don't have the `Source` of the image and the image is output of a method.

Comment: Well you still need to bind the source to the image. You can wrap up the logic for obtaining the image into a value converter (a class that implements IValueConverter) and specify that on the Binding.Converter